# Looping over data.frame by row to produce numerous nested XML records (HL7 format)

Tags: xml, r

I am currently trying to convert records in a data.frame into nested XML records using R. I have some experience parsing XML documents in R but have never needed to write them. I've tried looking for resources explaining how to do this but everything I've found has been extremely simplistic or only focuses on reading XML into R rather than writing it.

Here is an example of my data. The actual data is several hundred thousand rows.

```
example <- structure(list(patientid = c(10001, 10002, 10003, 10004, 10005, 10006, 10007, 10008, 10009, 100010), firstname = c("Jane1","Jane2", "Jane3", "Jane4", "Jane5", "Jane6", "Jane7", "Jane8", "Jane9","Jane10"), lastname = c("Doe1", "Doe2", "Doe3", "Doe4", "Doe5", "Doe6","Doe7", "Doe8", "Doe9", "Doe10"), middle = c("Middle1", "Middle2", "Middle3","Middle4", "Middle5", "Middle6", "Middle7", "Middle8", "Middle9", "Middle10"), dob = c("20150101", "20150102", "20150103", "20150104", "20150105","20150106", "20150107", "20150108", "20150109", "20150110"),organizationname = c("Practice 1", "Practice 2","Practice 3", "Practice 4","Practice 5", "Practice 6", "Practice 7","Practice 8", "Practice 9", "Practice 10"), organizationid = c(90L, 61L, 32L, 21L, 3L, 28L, 53L, 8L,60L, 3L), numericvalue1 = c(6.86105238215947, 13.0761869792404,1.33006454293633, 10.2726574035132, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.2213535916207,43.123550939618), numericunitcd = c("%", "%", "%", "%", "%","%", "%", "%", "%", "%"), observationcode = c("ASCVD-10YR","ASCVD-10YR", "ASCVD-10YR", "ASCVD-10YR", "ASCVD-10YR", "ASCVD-10YR","ASCVD-10YR", "ASCVD-10YR", "ASCVD-10YR", "ASCVD-10YR"),text = c("ASCVD 10 Year Risk Score", "ASCVD 10 Year Risk Score","ASCVD 10 Year Risk Score", "ASCVD 10 Year Risk Score", "ASCVD 10 Year Risk Score","ASCVD 10 Year Risk Score", "ASCVD 10 Year Risk Score", "ASCVD 10 Year Risk Score","ASCVD 10 Year Risk Score", "ASCVD 10 Year Risk Score"),observationcodesystem = c("CUSTOM", "CUSTOM", "CUSTOM","CUSTOM", "CUSTOM", "CUSTOM", "CUSTOM","CUSTOM", "CUSTOM", "CUSTOM"), dateofobservation = c("20150716","20150716", "20150716", "20150716", "20150716", "20150716","20150716", "20150716", "20150716", "20150716"), providerid = c(400001,400002, 400003, 400004, 400005, 400006, 400007, 400008, 400009,4000010), providerfirst = c("Doogie1", "Doogie2", "Doogie3","Doogie4", "Doogie5", "Doogie6", "Doogie7", "Doogie8", "Doogie9","Doogie10"), providerlast = c("Howser1", "Howser2", "Howser3","Howser4", "Howser5", "Howser6", "Howser7", "Howser8", "Howser9","Howser10")), .Names = c("patientid", "firstname", "lastname","middle", "dob", "organizationname", "organizationid", "numericvalue1","numericunitcd", "observationcode", "text", "observationcodesystem","dateofobservation", "providerid", "providerfirst", "providerlast"), row.names = c(1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 15L, 21L, 167392L, 167412L,167420L), class = "data.frame")
```

I ultimately need to write each row of data into the following (note: couldn't figure out a way to highlight the fields in question, but they are the column names from the above data.frame, i.e. `example$column`):

```
<HL7Message DomainID="1" DomainName="Domain" OrganizationID="example$organizationid" OrganizationName="example$organiationname" SourceSystem="DR">
    <MSH parentseq="-1" seq="1">
        <Segment component="-1" field="0" subcomponent="-1">MSH</Segment>
        <FieldSeparator component="-1" field="1" subcomponent="-1">|</FieldSeparator>
        <EncodingCharacters component="-1" field="2" subcomponent="-1">^~\&amp;</EncodingCharacters>
        <SendingFacility component="-1" field="4" subcomponent="-1">
            <NamespaceID component="1" field="4" subcomponent="-1">RP-1</NamespaceID>
        </SendingFacility>
        <DateTime component="-1" field="7" subcomponent="-1">
            <Time component="1" field="7" subcomponent="-1">systemdatetime</Time>
        </DateTime>
        <MessageType component="-1" field="9" subcomponent="-1">
            <MessageCode component="1" field="9" subcomponent="-1">ADT</MessageCode>
            <TriggerEvent component="2" field="9" subcomponent="-1">A28</TriggerEvent>
        </MessageType>
    </MSH>
    <PID parentseq="-1" seq="2">
        <Segment component="-1" field="0" subcomponent="-1">PID</Segment>
        <SetID-PID component="-1" field="1" subcomponent="-1">1</SetID-PID>
        <PatientIdentifierList component="-1" field="3" subcomponent="-1">
            <IDNumber component="1" field="3" subcomponent="-1">example$patientid</IDNumber>
        </PatientIdentifierList>
        <PatientName component="-1" field="5" subcomponent="-1">
            <FamilyName component="1" field="5" subcomponent="-1">
                <Surname component="1" field="5" subcomponent="1">example$firstname</Surname>
            </FamilyName>
            <GivenName component="2" field="5" subcomponent="-1">data$lastname</GivenName>
            <SecondAndFurtherGivenNames component="3" field="5" subcomponent="-1">example$middle</SecondAndFurtherGivenNames>
        </PatientName>
        <DateTimeOfBirth component="-1" field="7" subcomponent="-1">
            <Time component="1" field="7" subcomponent="-1">example$dob</Time>
        </DateTimeOfBirth>
    </PID>
    <PV1 parentseq="-1" seq="3">
        <Segment component="-1" field="0" subcomponent="-1">PV1</Segment>
        <SetID-PV1 component="-1" field="1" subcomponent="-1">1</SetID-PV1>
        <PatientClass component="-1" field="2" subcomponent="-1">O</PatientClass>
        <AssignedPatientLocation component="-1" field="3" subcomponent="-1">
            <PointOfCare component="1" field="3" subcomponent="-1">example$organizationname</PointOfCare>
        </AssignedPatientLocation>
        <AttendingDoctor component="-1" field="7" subcomponent="-1">
            <IDNumber component="1" field="7" subcomponent="-1">example$providerid</IDNumber>
            <FamilyName component="2" field="7" subcomponent="-1">
                <Surname component="2" field="7" subcomponent="1">example$providerlast</Surname>
            </FamilyName>
            <GivenName component="3" field="7" subcomponent="-1">example$providerfirst</GivenName>
        </AttendingDoctor>
        <ReferringDoctor component="-1" field="8" subcomponent="-1">
        </ReferringDoctor>
    </PV1>
    <OBX parentseq="3" seq="4">
        <Segment component="-1" field="0" parentseq="-1" subcomponent="-1">OBX</Segment>>
        <ObservationIdentifier component="-1" field="3" parentseq="-1" subcomponent="-1">
            <Identifier component="1" field="3" parentseq="-1" subcomponent="-1">example$observationcode</Identifier>
            <Text component="2" field="3" parentseq="-1" subcomponent="-1">example$text</Text>
            <NameofCodingSystem component="3" field="3" parentseq="-1" subcomponent="-1">example$observationcodesystem</NameofCodingSystem>
        </ObservationIdentifier>
        <ObservationValue component="-1" field="5" parentseq="-1" subcomponent="-1">
            <Identifier component="1" field="5" parentseq="-1" subcomponent="-1">example$numericvalue1</Identifier>
        </ObservationValue>
        <Units component="-1" field="6" parentseq="-1" subcomponent="-1">
            <Identifier component="1" field="6" parentseq="-1" subcomponent="-1">example$numericunitcd</Identifier>
        </Units>
        <ObservationResultStatus component="-1" field="11" parentseq="-1" subcomponent="-1">F</ObservationResultStatus>
        <DateTimeOfObservation component="-1" field="14" parentseq="-1" subcomponent="-1">
            <Time component="1" field="14" parentseq="-1" subcomponent="-1">example$dateofobservation</Time>
        </DateTimeOfObservation>
    </OBX>
    <ZPI parentseq="-1" seq="8">
        <Segment component="-1" field="0" subcomponent="-1">ZPI</Segment>
        <RecordType component="-1" field="1" subcomponent="-1">
            <Text component="2" field="1" subcomponent="-1">Risk Score</Text>
        </RecordType>
    </ZPI>
</HL7Message>
```

I've looked at the SaveXML {XML} and write.XML {kulife} functions, but still very much at a loss. Would I need to write each section (MSH, PID, PV1, OBX, ZPI) of a single row separately and then join them before looping to the next row of data? Thanks to anyone who can help me better understand how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
require(dplyr)
require(stringr)

xml_replacer <- function(df, xml_template, unique_id = "patientid") {
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    replacements <- unlist(df[i, ])
    names(replacements) <- paste0("<<",names(df), ">>")
    xml_result <- str_replace_all(xml_template, replacements)
    writeLines(xml_result, paste0(df[i, unique_id], "_xml_result.xml"))
  }
  return(TRUE)
}

xml_replacer(example, xml_lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply save your above template XML in a file, and `gsub` on it, particularly if you already know that your above template XML is well-formed.

e.g.

```
library(XML)
# helper function to sanitize strings for XML
sanitize <- function (str) {
    XML:::insertEntities(str, XML:::XMLEntities)
}

xmlTemplate <- readLines('template.xml')
xmlLines <- sapply(1:nrow(example),
       function (i) {
           o <- xmlTemplate
           for (n in names(example)) {
               # successively replace example$foo
               o <- gsub(paste0('example$', n), sanitize(example[i, n]), o, fixed=T)
           }
           o
       })
out.xml <- paste(xmlLines, collapse='\n')
```

To this purpose the `brew` package lets you template similarly to above. As long as you know your template XML is well-formed and isn't going to have other occurences of the string `example${something}` that should be left as-is, you'll be fine.

If you really want to do it in an XML-way, you could read in your template string into `XML`, set the appropriate attributes, and then write it out:

```
library(XML)

nodes <- lapply(1:nrow(example), function (i) {
    xmlTemplate <- xmlTreeParse('template.xml', useInternalNodes=T)
    n <- getNodeSet(xmlTemplate, '/HL7Message')[[1]]
    xmlAttrs(n) <- c(OrganizationID=example$organizationid[i], OrganizationName=example$organizationname[i])
    # and so on for all the other values you have to set.
    getNodeSet(xmlTemplate, '/HL7Message')[[1]]
    })

# Then write out all the nodes.
```

Bit more fiddly as you have to navigate to the appropriate attribute/value of each node and replace, but a bit more foolproof I guess. But as mentioned, if you know your template XML is well-formed you should be fine with a straight `gsub` along with `sanitize`.

Comment: Hi @mathematical.coffee. Thanks for the reply. I wanted to make sure that I  understand properly. For the first example, would I need to replace one field at a time, looping through all of the rows, then replace the next field, loop again, and repeat as many times as necessary?). If so, would subsequent loops grab out.xml rather than template.xml? `xmlTemplate <- readLines('out.xml')
xmlLines <- sapply(1:nrow(example),` Also for the 2nd example, would I only need to write out the notes that need replacing, or would I need to write out the entire XML regardless. Thanks again!